# select several consecutive XML tags in vim

Tags: xml, vim

I have the following XML file:

```
<outer>
  <middle>
    <inner>1</inner>
  </middle>
  <middle>
    <inner>2</inner>
  </middle>
  <middle>
    <inner>3</inner>
  </middle>
  <middle>
    <inner>4</inner>
  </middle>
</outer>
```

where I would select the whole `middle` `2` tag with `vat`.

Is there now a way to expand this selection to include the next `middle` tag (`3`) with some key combination?

I'd be only interested in doing this tagwise, that is, if there's a combination that can always be used independent of the structure of the next tag.

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the first tag block with `vat` press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd>   (`<c-v>j`) this will include the next `inner` (`3`)

**Edit:**

For your new example you can press `4$` after `vat` to get the tag block below.

**Edit:**

I wrote a script `ExpandTagBlock` which allows the expansion<sup>1</sup> of **same** tagblock by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd>:

```sh
nmap <silent> <F4> :set opfunc=ExpandTagBlock<CR>g@
vmap <silent> <F4> :<C-U>call ExpandTagBlock(visualmode(), 1)<CR>

function! Check()
    let str=@@
    if @@ =~# '\_s*<[^>]*\_.*</[^>]*>\_s*' 
        let str=substitute(str,'\_s*<[^>]*>\_.*\(<\/[^>]*>\)\_s*', '\1','g')
        return str
    else 
        return ''
    endif
endfunction

function! ExpandTagBlock(type, ...)
    let sel_save = &selection
    let &selection = "inclusive"
    let reg_save = @@

    if a:0  
        silent exe "normal! gvy"
    elseif a:type ==# 'line'
        silent exe "normal! '[V']y"
    else
        silent exe "normal! `[v`]y"
    endif
    let str=Check()
    if str ==# '' 
        echohl ErrorMsg | echomsg "Selection not a Tag block !" | echohl None
    else
        silent exe "silent! normal! gv/".escape(str,'/')."/e\r"
endif 

    let &selection = sel_save
    let @@ = reg_save
endfunction
```

Here is the **[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6gm0.gif)**:

[image]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The expansion of same tag block is done downwards only for now. The script is highly eligible for being improved or modified.</sub>

Comment: I guessed you meant to write lowercase `j`? the `J` would join the lines instead. Still, this just works linewise, I changed the example to clarify the question

Comment: For your new example you can expand it by typing `3j` or `4$`.

Answer (score 0):

Meninx's answer is indeed correct with vanilla vim. The following assumes you're selecting those tags because you want to do stuff to them. You might not actually need to be selecting them at all if vim had additional definitions for text objects.

If you're editing XML (or HTML, etc. for that matter) on a regular basis however, you might want to look into Tim Pope's plug-ins that add motions for "parentheses, brackets, quotes, XML tags, and more." This builds on the idea that vim's editing style is based on "text objects", i.e. words, sentences, paragraphs and tags.

For example in vanilla vim, `caw` will "change around word". Using the plug-in mentioned below, you'll be able to do things like `cs'<q>`, which would "change surrounding single quotes with the tag `<q>...</q>`".

**vim-surround** adds general-use motions for "surroundings", which is one of the most frequently used plugins in all the vim dotfiles I've seen floating around:

- https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

You can also check out **vim-ragtag**, that adds extended support for XML, HTML, PHP, etc. tags, and enhances vim-surround. I don't use it myself, but it's a set of shortcuts mapped to `C-X`, i.e. `C-X-<CR>` will wrap "foo" into:

```
<foo>
^
</foo>
```

- https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag

Another contender is machakann's vim-sandwich. Check it out here:

- https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich

---

If you don't have a vim plug-in manager, may I suggest using [junegunn's **vim-plug**](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug).

Once vim-plug is [set up](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/faq), installing the first two plug-ins would be as easy as adding the following lines to your .vimrc:

```
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'tpope/vim-ragtag'
```